# Graphql parameter returning optional(optional("value")) - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo

I am using GraphQL API's in my project using Apollo. I called many API with graphql and it return success , but now I am trying to call an API using some parameters it returning value as, optional(optional("value")) and return the result as empty.

I am passing the parameter as,

```
let filterInput = FilterInput(title: "car")
print("filterInput....", filterInput)
self.getAllProducts(pgNum: 0, filterInput: filterInput)
```

**Actual result:**

> filterInput : FilterInput(graphQLMap: ["title": Optional(Optional("car")), "transmissionId": nil, "location": nil, "radius": nil, "mileageTo": nil, "serviceId": nil, "seatCountTo": nil, "model": nil])

**Expected result:**

> filterInput : FilterInput(graphQLMap: ["title": "car", "transmissionId": nil, "location": nil, "radius": nil, "mileageTo": nil, "serviceId": nil, "seatCountTo": nil, "model": nil])

This is my query code,

```
  func getAllProducts(pgNum: Int , filterInput : FilterInput)
  {
    self.imageArr.removeAll()
    self.checkPageNumber = self.pageNumber
    apollo.fetch(query: GetAllProductsQuery(filter: filterInput, pageNumber: String(pgNum))){ (result, error) in
        let productDetails = result?.data?.getAllProducts
        if productDetails?.count == 0
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.hideActivityIndicator()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if result?.data?.getAllProducts != nil{
                for i in 0...(result?.data?.getAllProducts?.count)!-1
                {
                    let index = productDetails![i]
                    let productId = index?.id
                    let productTitle = index?.title

                    let imageArr = index?.images
                    if imageArr!.count > 0
                    {
                        self.imageArr.append(imageArr![0]!)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self.imageArr.append("")
                    }

                    self.productIdArr.append(productId!)
                    self.productTitleArr.append(productTitle!)

                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.productImageArr = self.productImageArr + self.imageArr
                    self.productCollectionView.reloadData()
                    self.singleTonInstance.allProductImages  = self.productImageArr

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please share your query?

Comment: Updated my code, please refer that

Comment: The reason is too many question marks and too much optional chaining. This is pretty *objective-c-ish* and has an ugly impact in Swift. Unwrap the optionals safely.

Comment: but I also tried to passed the parameter value as static , so how can I unwrap safely

Comment: Hey @AngelFSyrus, Have you solved this?

Comment: I didn't found any solution for that issue  :(